# how to properly use async database operations in node backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

Let's say we have a model in our database (mongoDB) called `User` with one property `email` in it.

Now we want to make a `createUser` function that will check if email is valid and if there is no user with that email already in our database.

We could write:
(using mongoose)

1.

Make the createUser funstion asynchronous with async and then wait for the database's result

`const result = await User.find({email: email})`

after this we could do a normal syncronous validation like

`const isValid = email === "test@test.com'`

and then execute `User.create(...)`

but it would have to wait for the result before executing ANY code right ? (not a good idea for a backend)

2.

Make it a chain of promises or callbacks but the code readability would be quite poor.

What is a good option in such a case if we'd want to create a nice non-blocking backend?

Answer (score 0):

async/await is basically syntactic sugar for a promise chain, so it's not doing anything different. So on the backend it's fine.